# Is there a function to split cells that will ignore delimiters within quotation marks?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I am trying to separate CSV text into columns using a formula in google sheets, but when I do it ends up separating strings with commas within quotes.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bqG82qVNv8_VaSarVHFJ4dn78khf_2nNajRe9-ulXL4/edit?usp=sharing

For example when I use

```
=split(A1,","):
```

```
119,"6.65","","en","Ezuri, Renegade Leader","6734497c-16f0-4c4b-ba24-337333511fc6","1","rare","e9544132-bbb5-4ec4-af82-dad56e5091af","som","Scars of Mirrodin"
```

Gets turned into:

| 119 | 6.65 | en | Ezuri | Renegade Leader | 6734497c-16f0-4c4b-ba24-337333511fc6 | 1 | rare | e9544132-bbb5-4ec4-af82-dad56e5091af | som | Scars of Mirrodin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"""?,""",""),"")
```

Steps:

Replace `","` and `,"` with :

```
"1196.65enEzuri, Renegade Leader6734497c-16f0-4c4b-ba24-337333511fc61raree9544132-bbb5-4ec4-af82-dad56e5091afsomScars of Mirrodin"
```

and split by :

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 119 | 6.65 | en | Ezuri, Renegade Leader | 6734497c-16f0-4c4b-ba24-337333511fc6 | 1 | rare | e9544132-bbb5-4ec4-af82-dad56e5091af | som " | Scars of Mirrodin""" |

Comment: I ended up doing something similar.

I lopped the left collector number off 
=left(A2,FIND(",",A2)-1) 

then I used this formula: 
=SPLIT(LEFT(right(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND(",",A2)-1),LEN(right(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND(",",A2)-1))-1),char(34)&","&char(34),,false)